# Stacking DIVS on Top Of Each Other In Ascending Order

Tags: html, css

I'm stacking divs on top of each other, it works but how can I stack them in ascending order instead of descending order like default? See this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/prBQNE).

The end result should be `blue` `green` `yellow` `red` as opposed to default DOM `red` `yellow` `green` `blue`. Any idea?

**css**

```
.inner {
position: absolute;
}
span{
  visibility:hidden;
}
.blue{
 background:blue;
}
.green{
 background:green;
}
.yellow{
 background:yellow;
}
.red{
 background:red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner blue"><span>inner</span></div>
   <div class="inner green"><span>inner</span></div>
   <div class="inner yellow"><span>inner</span></div>
   <div class="inner red"><span>inner</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stack them on top of each other like overlapping layers, then `z-index` will let you choose which order they should stack in.

```
.blue{
  background:blue;
  z-index: 4;
}
.green{
  background:green;
  z-index: 3;
}
.yellow{
  background:yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}
.red{
  background:red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Codepen showing it in action here.](https://codepen.io/fredrivett/pen/yorQgg)

Comment: Thanks for answering but when I stack the divs on top of one another it gives same result. In your code you've removed `.inner {
position: absolute;
}` I need it there.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you meant stack vertically, not on top of each other like layers. I've updated my answer and codepen to match here.